# Simple Share Buttons Add Plugin and Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, filters, buttons

First of all [Simple Share Buttons Add](https://simplesharebuttons.com/) is a great plugin to share WordPress contents to social media.
Nonetheless, I encountered an issue with it. It is not possible to disable these button on custom post types while enabling it on posts. How to overcome that ?

Comment: Not clear: You got an issue with a plugin, but managed to write the question, find the solution and write an answer in less than a minute? It's a record, isn't it?

Comment: This is a bad plugin with various vulnerabilities (redirects etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

You need to hook an action to remove ssba button. [Wp action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) runs pretty early and allow you to remove the ssba filter on the content which add the buttons list.

```
function remove_share_buttons_custom_post() {
  if (in_array(get_post_type(),array('sar'))) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'show_share_buttons');
  }
}
add_action('wp', 'remove_share_buttons_custom_post');
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to your code